# File picker opens twice once button is submitted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

There's an issue that I cannot figured: When the button Generate Report is pressed, the window to select a file for upload pops out correctly, however this happens twice. Why is this happening?

```
<div ng-controller="AppController as forms">
    <legend>Report</legend>
    <uib-tabset active="active">
        <uib-tab index="0" ng-click="setReportType(templOne)" heading="Report One">
            <div Report-non-customers></div>
        </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="1" ng-click="setReportType(templTwo)" heading="Report Two">
            <div Report-customers></div>
        </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>

    <form id="form-ui" method="POST" name="form" novalidate>
    <div class="frm-row">
        <div class="section colm colm12">
            <label class="field-label colm ">House Type:</label>
            <label class="field select">
                <select ng-model="dropdown.houseType" ng-options="x for (x, y) in forms">
                    <option value="">Select House Type</option>
                </select>
                <i class="arrow"></i>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select a file:</label>
        <input type="file" accept=".json" fileread="data">
    </div>
    <button class="button btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="submit()">
        Generate Report
    </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you should remove `method="POST"` from your form and add `ng-submit="submit()"` (removing `ng-click="submit()"` from a button)

Comment: Done that and it's still happening.

Comment: button type submit automatically submit the form. No need to use ng-click.

Comment: To prevent double execution of the handler, use only one of the `ngSubmit` or `ngClick` directives. Read [AngularJS `<form>` Directive API Reference - Submitting a form and preventing the default action](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action).

Comment: The `<input type="file">` element has a non-standard directive named `fileread`. Show us the code for that directive. Also show us the code for the `submit()` function.